# mysqldump - right command wrong execution

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code.

```
<?php
    $command = '/usr/bin/mysqldump --user=marvin --password=mypassword --host=localhost opencart_status > /var/www/marvin/backup.sql';
    $result = passthru($command, $report);
    if(!$report){
        echo "Error!";
    }
    else{
        echo "OK";
    }
?>
```

I tried to run the `$command` on putty in linux and everything is OK. But when I ran it in my php scirpt, the output was "OK" (`echo "OK"`), but no backup.sql was in my folder.

Comment: does the webserver have write permissions in that directory?

Comment: And is there a reason you run the command twice?

Comment: @Yes, it has the permissions and there is no reason to run it twice. Mistake appeared when I ran more possibilities.

Comment: Try adding `2>&1` before `>` to get error messages from the command line.

Comment: OK, I have it! I had to give my php file into the directory, set permissions for all users and add to php mkdir command. There I'll save my output.

`<?php
 $path = './SQL';
 if(!is_dir($path)){
  mkdir($path, 0777, true);
 }

 $filename='database_backup_'.date('G_a_m_d_y').'.sql';
 $command = '/usr/bin/mysqldump --user=marvin --password=mypassword --host=localhost opencart_status > /var/www/kukin/backup/SQL/'.$filename;
 $result = passthru($command, $report);
 
?>`